# Use database which ends with the current year in a view Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

how can i put the current year dinamically at the and of the database name.

Example

```
select
`d`.`matricolaFMVOra` as `ID_ADDETTO`,
`t`.`Data` as `DATA`,
`t`.`Orario` as `INIZIO_LAVORO`,
'0' as `MOTIVAZIONE`,
`t1`.`Orario` as `FINE_LAVORO` 
from
(
    (
        `dbname_YEAR`.`table` `t` join `dbname_YEAR`.`table` `t1` on
        (
            (
                `t`.`Data` = `t1`.`Data`
            )
        )
    )
/**other code**/
```

Is it possible?
Thank you

Comment: yes it is possible? handle using db stored procedure or server side script.

Comment: yes but, view's cannot accept parameters

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL.  I would generally discourage anyone from setting up their databases this way, but it is probably too late for that.

Comment: I can't use dynamic SQL in a view, that's not a query for create new table, but it's a query for show data in a view

Comment: What you are asking is not possible in a view but i think that if you are using 5.7 + you might have a similar solution using create_synonym_db() although you'd have to change it annually.